# phalcon and phalcon devtools installation issue in windows 10

Tags: php, windows-10, wamp, phalcon, phalcon-devtools

I am trying to create a new phalcon project in my machine which has windows 10 with wamp server installed. I tried to create the project in different ways. I have tried with pecl and phalcon windows dll with configuring php.ini. I tried to install the devtools via composer.I have downloaded the devtools devtools-master repo and paste that in c drive then setting up system variable for that.But when I try to create a project using phalcon or check the version of the phalcon everytime it says error: please install composer. And it is repeating even after I install the composer.

But every time it seems like some compatible issues with php version or phalcon version with phalcon dev tools. Can anyone suggest me the steps I should follow  to create a fresh phalcon project on windows 10 with wamp server installed?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if devtools is ready for v.5. What you can do is take one of the MVC examples (https://github.com/phalcon/mvc) and copy & paste the one that suits your project.